# error while compiling Libvlc in a C Project

Tags: c, makefile, libvlc, gtk2

I am trying to compile a simple code of libvlc found here [libvlc tuto](https://wiki.videolan.org/LibVLC_Tutorial/)
in a C project using gtk+2 on ubuntu

but I have an error message like this In function `main`:
`/home/bilel/esprit-2015-3b1-geekinnovators-svn/pp/src/main.c:65: undefined reference to 'libvlc_new'`.

Comment: This is issue has been discussed in the below stack overflow link, pl. checkhttp://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429338/undefined-reference-to-libvlc-new-but-linked-correctly

Comment: Have you installed libvlc-dev?

Comment: I already saw it and try it but i mentioned that i am using C language and i did not assimilate it right ..

Comment: @AugustKarlstrom yes i have ..

Answer (score 0):

You need to link with *libvlc*. Append `-lvlc` to the compilation command.

Example:

```
cc -Wall test.c -lvlc
```

Also, the example should include the POSIX header file unistd.h which contains the declaration of the function *sleep*.

Comment: The file where the vlc code is compiled and i have the executable now but i want to link it to the project when i add vlc.c (where the code is ) to the makefile.am i have the same errors .. i want to to set the two executables together ..

Comment: @Bine13 add `-lvlc` to *AM_LDFLAGS* in Makefile.am.

Comment: `   ## Process this file with automake to produce Makefile.in `

    INCLUDES = \
-DPACKAGE_DATA_DIR=\""$(datadir)"\" \
-DPACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR=\""$(prefix)/$(DATADIRNAME)/locale"\" \
@PACKAGE_CFLAGS@

bin_PROGRAMS = projet-c

projet_c_SOURCES = \
main.c  \
support.c support.h \
interface.c interface.h \
callbacks.c callbacks.h \
windows.c windows.h \
Authentification.c Authentification.h \
Alertes.c Alertes.h \
camera.c camera.h \
hello-world.c hello-world.h \
    ajoutagent.c Agents.h 



projet_c_LDADD = @PACKAGE_LIBS@ $(INTLLIBS)